# Hide/Show Element function is undefined?

Tags: javascript

Learning JS and was following a complex tutorial and keep getting errors for these specific functions. Stating that my "hide and show element" functions are undefined? Which i thought was odd since they are definitions kinda? Mostly confused because worked fine for the person in the video tutorial.

Any help understanding why is much appreciated!

```js
'use strict';

hideElement = (element) => element.style.display = 'none';
showElement = (element) => element.style.display = 'block';

hideElement('connectWalletBtn');
showElement('userProfileBtn');

// define user button elements
const connectWalletBtn = document.getElementById('connectWalletBtn');
const userProfileBtn = document.getElementById('userProfileBtn');
```

```html
<button id="connectWalletBtn">Connect Wallet</button>
<button id="userProfileBtn">Profile</button>
```

Comment: Your functions expect an element, but you are calling them with a `string`. Go with `hideElement(connectWalletBtn);` instead.

Comment: I forgot the bottom snippet defining the buttons in my snippet. I added it now. Still getting undefined.

Comment: You are still passing strings, not the variables declared.

Comment: Yep that was my problem. I cant believe i didnt realize this after everything ive learned lol

Comment: That is how you learn the best, by making mistakes.

Comment: Voting to close as _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you have never defined your variables for your functions. Do that:

```
const hideElement = (element) => element.style.display = 'none';
const showElement = (element) => element.style.display = 'block';
```

Second, your functions expect to get passed an `element`, but you are calling them with a `string`. Go with

```
hideElement(connectWalletBtn);
showElement(userProfileBtn);
```

instead.

The third problem is that you're using constant variables which you only declare after using them.

As an improvement, to toggle the display property of an element between `none` and `initial`, the DOM API has the `hidden` property/attribute (which sync). Use it.

Here's the corrected snippet:

```js
'use strict';
const hideElement = element => element.hidden = true;
const showElement = element => element.hidden = false;

// make sure the DOM is fully parsed so elements 
// are available for Javascript access
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // find user button elements and store references in variables
  const connectWalletBtn = document.getElementById('connectWalletBtn');
  const userProfileBtn = document.getElementById('userProfileBtn');

  hideElement(connectWalletBtn);
  showElement(userProfileBtn);
})
```

```html
<button id="connectWalletBtn">Connect Wallet</button>
<button id="userProfileBtn">Profile</button>
```

Comment: really worth an answer and not a comment and a close as typo?

Comment: I think it wasn't just a typo. It's a beginner that confuses strings and variable names. Also there's more problems, see updated answer.

Comment: Yes there were more problems i am going through your solution now

Comment: Ah, so you complain that I use .hidden= instead of setAttribute("hidden", boolean) and then you use it yourself? Why even write a function then?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to grab the element from the dom.

```
    hideElement = (element) => document.getElementById(element).style.display = 'none';
    showElement = (element) => document.getElementById(element).style.display = 'block';
```